# Open Netflix from Android App and login by passing credentials

Tags: android, android-intent

I've implemented a functionality to open Netflix app from my Android App.

Now I want to pass login credentials with Intent for enabling auto-login for the user.
Is it feasible? 
Or is there some other way out?

Answer (score 2):

Not unless the Netflix app has this functionality built in; and I would be dumbfounded if it does.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want to pass login credentials with Intent for enabling auto-login for the user. Is it feasible?

No.

Whether or not the receiving app supports this type of 'remote login' is of course crucial information, but not important to decide if it's feasible.

See, intents are not some secret *can't touch this* thing. An external application/person can monitor intents and view their contents. You don't want to send credentials in an intent.